# Tab box sized by biggest panel content in pure CSS

Tags: css, tabs, flexbox, css-float, dynamic-sizing

Using floats, flexbox or a table, there are different methods to size two adjacent blocks to the same height or to the same width, dependent on their contents **without using JavaScript.**

I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same for panels of a tab box, of which only one is visible at a time.

So if for example a panel is empty, its size (or at least its background) should be extended to the size of the biggest panel in the stack of panels.

My intention is to prevent elements below or beside the tab box to jump to different positions when the tab is switched, but I don't want to assume anything about the dimensions of the panel contents since they are dynamic.

Comment: Please share your code with us or better create some example otherwise it will be hard for us to help you.

Comment: One approach was to arrange the tab panels side by side and set `overflow: hidden` on their parent. Then on tab switch, the parent's x-offset would be changed so the selected tab would move into the visible area. But this way, the tab box width needs to be fixed and also the x-offset of each panel would need to be hard-coded, so the css would have to change for a different number of panels :(

Comment: @Daniel, we need to see your code. Please edit your question with it.

Comment: @Option since this is a conceptual question, there is no code yet. Examples of tab box implementations that show the unintended behavior can be [found](http://onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-tab-with-fade-animation/) [all](http://cssmojo.com/pure-css-tab-panel/) [over](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/) [the](http://sevensignature.com/blog/demo/responsive-pure-css-tabs/) [web](http://cssscript.com/demo/creating-a-stylish-tabs-control-using-pure-css-css3).

Comment: @daniel, i'm afraid no body will write out custom code for benefits given there's been no attempt on doing this yourself.

Comment: @Option Writing out custom code I can do by myself, I don't expect anybody to do this for me. Since "I wonder if there is a way…", I am just asking for a general approach to achieve the intended behavior.

Comment: If your question is "I wonder if there is a way?" then it is too broad and/or primarily opinion-based for SO, so if you want a proper answer I suggest you add a code sample showing what you have and what you look for.

Comment: @LGSon SO is not and should not be limited to getting syntax right and tell people to RTFM. It's for 'developers looking for solutions' by their own definition. In this case, I think the problem is fairly common to a lot of people who are using tab boxes. And the solution could be just one sentence saying "this flexbox css property might be helpful", or "on this page, the problem is tackled using that method" or even "pure CSS is not suited to tackle this kind of problem because reason".

Comment: @LGSon Actually I tried and wrote a lot of code, but to rely only on specific source code and to fiddle around with it doesn't seem like a professional practice and only narrows down the possible spectrum of solutions or ideas. If you don't want to or cannot handle the question on a conceptual level, take a look at the many examples I referred to in my previous comment. It's not a matter of opinion but about the fact if something is possible in pure CSS (and how) or if it is beyond the scope (and why).

Comment: _It's for 'developers looking for solutions' by their own definition._, for developers, yes, by their own definition, not if the question gets too broad or is opinion-based. Now, yours might not be that so I decided to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox and `visibility: collapse` (see [W3C draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#visibility-collapse)), contents can be hidden while the occupied space is still taken into account.

The following example is working on IE and Firefox, not (yet) in Safari, Opera and Chrome [[in progress]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174167).

```js
var count = 0;
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');
document.querySelector('button')
.addEventListener('click', function () {
  children[count++ % 4].classList.toggle('show');
  children[count   % 4].classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.container div.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="show">
    1. Some text
  </div>
  <div>
    2. Some more text<br/>
    Some more text
  </div>
  <div>
    3. Some even more text<br/>
    Some even more text<br/>
    Some even more text<br/>
    Some even more text<br/>
    Some even more text
  </div>
  <div>
    4. Some more text<br/>
    Some more text
  </div>
</div>

<p>Text below, does not move on toggle.</p>
```

Comment: This will soon be the better solution :) ... upvoted

Answer (score 1):

On a conceptual level, and on how I understood your question, you will need a row structure, like a table or a flexbox, where siblings on the same row sizes equal.

Since each panel's content should behave as if it were alone, it need to have the width of its container, or else the content will start wrap and effect its siblings height.

So to allow a normal flow I added a wrapper and *nn* times amount of children as width and then used `transform: translate` to pull them on top of each other, so one can animate between them without anything moves.

Here is a sample code using `flexbox`, which I also recommend to use.

---

Updated based on a comment.

One can of course predefine this in the same way one does when making i.e. a grid, where you setup a max amount of tabs you need and then it will work with up to that amount, here defined for 12 but only using 7

*And this works today, no need to wait for Chrome :)*

```js
(function (count) {
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  var children = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    children[count].classList.toggle('show');
    count++; if (count == children.length) count = 0;
    children[count].classList.toggle('show');
  })
})(0);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 1200%;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 12);
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.wrapper div.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2)  { transform: translate(-100%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(3)  { transform: translate(-200%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(4)  { transform: translate(-300%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(5)  { transform: translate(-400%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(6)  { transform: translate(-500%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(7)  { transform: translate(-600%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(8)  { transform: translate(-700%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(9)  { transform: translate(-800%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(10) { transform: translate(-900%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(11) { transform: translate(-1000%); }
.wrapper div:nth-child(12) { transform: translate(-1100%); }


/*  styling stuff  */
button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="show">
      1. Some text
    </div>
    <div>
      2. Some more text<br> Some more text<br>
    </div>
    <div>
      3. Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> 
Some even more text<br>     </div>
    <div>
      4. Some more text<br> Some more text<br>
    </div>
    <div>
      5. Some text
    </div>
    <div>
      6. Some more text<br> Some more text<br>
    </div>
    <div>
      7. Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> Some even more text<br> 
Some even more text<br>     </div>
  </div>
  The height is kept so text like this does not move 
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I described in my first comment above. It kind of solves the problem, but this way, new panels cannot be just added without having to re-write all the `left` properties.

Comment: @DanielWacker Thas is an easy fix...updated my answer

Comment: @DanielWacker So now this actually solve all your problems